# ¿How can I declare a EditorFor of decimal type in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code in the view

```
@Html.EditorFor(model = model.Debe, new{htmlAtributes = new{@class="form-control bor"}})
```

The error that shows me

```
System.InvalidOperation.Exception:'The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type'System.Decimal'.'
```

The view model

```
[Required]
public decimal Debe {get; set;}
```

Comment: This is not a problem with `EditorFor`. It's a problem with your controller. What are you returning from your action?

Comment: You're missing a ">".  should be model=>model.Debe